# Problem ef core generated query after migration 2.1 to 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I migrated ef core 2.1 to 6.0
I have a weird behavior with the below code :

```
vehicles = _context.Vehicles
      .Where(v => v.VehicleDetail.BuyingDate.HasValue && v.VehicleDetail.BuyingDate.Value.Year == year &&
                 (v.VehicleDetail.VehicleType == VehicleTypeEnum.CAR || v.VehicleDetail.VehicleType == VehicleTypeEnum.VAN))
      .Include(v => v.VehicleDetail)
      .Include(v => v.Phase).ThenInclude(p => p.Model).ThenInclude(m => m.Brand)
      .OrderBy(v => v.NoCleanup)
      .Distinct().ToList();
```

With ef core 2.1, the query generated :

```
SELECT DISTINCT [v].[Id], [v].[CirculationDate], [v].[Convention], [v].[Destination], [v].[Energy], [v].[EngineNumber], [v].[EntryDate], [v].[GearboxNumber], [v].[Mileage], [v].[Motorization_id], [v].[NoCleanup], [v].[Observations], [v].[Phase_id], [v].[Registration], [v].[Registration2], [v].[Registration3], [v].[Site_id], [v].[Todo], [v].[Tour_id], [v].[UpdateDate], [v].[UpdatedBy], [v.Phase].[Id], [v.Phase].[EntryDate], [v.Phase].[Model_id], [v.Phase].[Name], [v.Phase].[UpdateDate], [v.Phase].[UpdatedBy], [v.Phase.Model].[Id], [v.Phase.Model].[Brand_id], [v.Phase.Model].[EntryDate], [v.Phase.Model].[Name], [v.Phase.Model].[UpdateDate], [v.Phase.Model].[UpdatedBy], [v.Phase.Model.Brand].[Id], [v.Phase.Model.Brand].[EntryDate], [v.Phase.Model.Brand].[Name], [v.Phase.Model.Brand].[UpdateDate], [v.Phase.Model.Brand].[UpdatedBy], [v.VehicleDetail].[Id], [v.VehicleDetail].[AdministrativeObservations], [v.VehicleDetail].[AssignementDate], [v.VehicleDetail].[AssignementSendingBy], [v.VehicleDetail].[Burnt], [v.VehicleDetail].[BuyPrice], [v.VehicleDetail].[BuyerPaymentMode], [v.VehicleDetail].[Buyer_id], [v.VehicleDetail].[BuyingDate], [v.VehicleDetail].[Cnit], [v.VehicleDetail].[CrusherDate], [v.VehicleDetail].[DateGivenFolder], [v.VehicleDetail].[DateOfDestruction], [v.VehicleDetail].[DateRequestPayment], [v.VehicleDetail].[EmptyWeight], [v.VehicleDetail].[EntryDate], [v.VehicleDetail].[Expert_id], [v.VehicleDetail].[InSettlement], [v.VehicleDetail].[Insurance_id], [v.VehicleDetail].[Origin], [v.VehicleDetail].[PaymentMode], [v.VehicleDetail].[RecipientAssignementByLetter], [v.VehicleDetail].[SellPrice], [v.VehicleDetail].[Seller_id], [v.VehicleDetail].[Selling], [v.VehicleDetail].[SellingDate], [v.VehicleDetail].[SerialNumber], [v.VehicleDetail].[SettlementDate], [v.VehicleDetail].[UpdateDate], [v.VehicleDetail].[UpdatedBy], [v.VehicleDetail].[VehicleType], [v.VehicleDetail].[Vehicle_id], [v.VehicleDetail].[isPurchaseForDestruction]
FROM [Vehicles] AS [v]
LEFT JOIN [Phases] AS [v.Phase] ON [v].[Phase_id] = [v.Phase].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Models] AS [v.Phase.Model] ON [v.Phase].[Model_id] = [v.Phase.Model].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [v.Phase.Model.Brand] ON [v.Phase.Model].[Brand_id] = [v.Phase.Model.Brand].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [VehiclesDetails] AS [v.VehicleDetail] ON [v].[Id] = [v.VehicleDetail].[Vehicle_id]
WHERE ([v.VehicleDetail].[BuyingDate] IS NOT NULL AND (DATEPART(year, [v.VehicleDetail].[BuyingDate]) = 2021)) AND (([v.VehicleDetail].[VehicleType] = 0) OR ([v.VehicleDetail].[VehicleType] = 4))
ORDER BY [v].[NoCleanup]
```

with ef core 6 :

```
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[CirculationDate], [t].[Convention], [t].[Destination], [t].[Energy], [t].[EngineNumber], [t].[EntryDate], [t].[GearboxNumber], [t].[Mileage], [t].[Motorization_id], [t].[NoCleanup], [t].[Observations], [t].[Phase_id], [t].[Registration], [t].[Registration2], [t].[Registration3], [t].[Site_id], [t].[Todo], [t].[Tour_id], [t].[UpdateDate], [t].[UpdatedBy], [v1].[Id], [v1].[AdministrativeObservations], [v1].[AssignementDate], [v1].[AssignementSendingBy], [v1].[Burnt], [v1].[BuyPrice], [v1].[BuyerPaymentMode], [v1].[Buyer_id], [v1].[BuyingDate], [v1].[Cnit], [v1].[CrusherDate], [v1].[DateGivenFolder], [v1].[DateOfDestruction], [v1].[DateRequestPayment], [v1].[EmptyWeight], [v1].[EntryDate], [v1].[Expert_id], [v1].[InSettlement], [v1].[Insurance_id], [v1].[Origin], [v1].[PaymentMode], [v1].[RecipientAssignementByLetter], [v1].[SellPrice], [v1].[Seller_id], [v1].[Selling], [v1].[SellingDate], [v1].[SerialNumber], [v1].[SettlementDate], [v1].[UpdateDate], [v1].[UpdatedBy], [v1].[VehicleType], [v1].[Vehicle_id], [v1].[isPurchaseForDestruction], [p].[Id], [p].[EntryDate], [p].[Model_id], [p].[Name], [p].[UpdateDate], [p].[UpdatedBy], [m].[Id], [m].[Brand_id], [m].[EntryDate], [m].[Name], [m].[UpdateDate], [m].[UpdatedBy], [b].[Id], [b].[EntryDate], [b].[Name], [b].[UpdateDate], [b].[UpdatedBy]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [v].[Id], [v].[CirculationDate], [v].[Convention], [v].[Destination], [v].[Energy], [v].[EngineNumber], [v].[EntryDate], [v].[GearboxNumber], [v].[Mileage], [v].[Motorization_id], [v].[NoCleanup], [v].[Observations], [v].[Phase_id], [v].[Registration], [v].[Registration2], [v].[Registration3], [v].[Site_id], [v].[Todo], [v].[Tour_id], [v].[UpdateDate], [v].[UpdatedBy]
    FROM [Vehicles] AS [v]
    LEFT JOIN [VehiclesDetails] AS [v0] ON [v].[Id] = [v0].[Vehicle_id]
    WHERE ([v0].[BuyingDate] IS NOT NULL AND (DATEPART(year, [v0].[BuyingDate]) = 2021)) AND [v0].[VehicleType] IN (0, 4)
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [VehiclesDetails] AS [v1] ON [t].[Id] = [v1].[Vehicle_id]
LEFT JOIN [Phases] AS [p] ON [t].[Phase_id] = [p].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Models] AS [m] ON [p].[Model_id] = [m].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [b] ON [m].[Brand_id] = [b].[Id]
```

I don't understand the FROM and why the ORDER BY disapear

Comment: OrderBy before Distinct has no sense in SQL world. And, probably, EF Core removed this as part of optimisation. So better put OrderBy after Distinct. LINQ translation is very complex task and EF Core tried to solve it by it's own translator (before it was ReLinq).

Comment: Additional Subquery in `FROM` - you can call it as an optimisation, because it reduces count of fields which are used in `DISTINCT`, which means better SQL Server resources usage.

Comment: Also `DISTINCT` has no absolutely no sense here when `v.Id` is unique.